# What's the difference between pressing S and Alt+S?

Tags: transforms, shortcut

Sometimes I see <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> online but I don't notice a difference between it or just using <kbd>S</kbd>. What does <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> do?

I don't get Blender wiki's brief explanation.

Comment: Someone changed my title. I put alt +s not -s

Comment: In Edit Mode *ALT S* is used to ***Scale Along Normals*** in other words it moves each vertex in the direction of its local normal, shrinking or fattening the mesh.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The key command <kbd>S</kbd> is used to scale whatever is selected in the viewport, regardless of mode. However using the command <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to scale selection along the normals is only possible in Edit Mode.

When you scale the object, all the distance ratios between various vertices and all angles will remain exactly the same, just get larger or smaller:

[image: Scale Edit Mode]

However when using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> command, blender will try to shrink or fatten the mesh. This can lead to unusual results if done on certain meshes:

[image: Shrink Fatten Edit Mode]

I have noticed that it works much better with more vertices. This really shows exactly what is happening. The inner vertices appear to have a greater weight, being moved a much greater distance. This leads to a convex shape after fattening, or a concave shape after shrinking.

[image]

Comment: How did you get that mode popup??

Comment: @ajwood 2.72+ comes with the *Pie Menus* addon, search for it in the *User Preferences* :)

Comment: Cool, now I get it.

Comment: @luigi good :-)

Answer (score 3):

In *Object mode* <kbd>S</kbd> scales and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> clears the scaling i.e. the scaling is reset to 1.
You can verify this in the *Properties Panel* <kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for alt + s simultaneously.