# Alt+S doesn`t work as expected

Tags: modeling

I`m working on a model for 3d printing. I wanted to make it hollow, so i made a duplicate with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and wanted to scale it inwards with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>...
I expected something like in this question explained:
[Alt+S and S scaling](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26635/whats-the-difference-between-pressing-s-and-alts)

scaling with <kbd>S</kbd> I get something like that
[image]

but with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> I get this and cannot scale :(
[image]

scaling only with <kbd>S</kbd> I don't get an evenly thick frame... so I don't know how to solve this.

Thank you in advance and happy modeling :)

Comment: Will solidify modifier be a good solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are only able to do the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> command while your in edit mode. From what I see in the second picture you posted, your'er in object mode. And for future key commands that don't work just go to the wiki for them, like at the bottom of [this  page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Transformations/Basics/Scale) 
it shows the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> command you were asking about, and that it needs to be used in edit mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i overlooked this part >.< sorry and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Solidify modifier, adding 2 more materials to the rim and the internal faces, then apply the modifier, then select the material of outer mesh and hide it and use smooth sculpt brush to smooth the areas ears eyes and the mouth that are poking out through the outer mesh.